# Function/procedure/view or anything else with dynamic parameters in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

lets say I have table *issues* with following data:

```
+------+------------+
| id   | project_id |
+------+------------+
|  101 |          2 |
|  102 |          2 |
|  103 |          2 |
|  104 |          2 |
|  105 |          2 |
|  106 |          2 |
|  107 |          2 |
|  123 |          9 |
|  234 |         63 |
|  454 |         77 |
|  893 |         73 |
| 1233 |        101 |
+------+------------+
```

And for example I want to count number of issues in projects with project_id 2,64 and 77. I can do that with following SQL statement

```
select count(*) from issues where project_id in (2,64,77);
```

But what if I didn't want to create this statement every time but save it somehow and just pass the ids of projects i need count for?
So I would need something like following function which I can call like

```
select my_function(2,64,77);
```

But the problem is it seems like I can't create function with such dynamic parameters. Is there any way to do that? Of course it doesn't have to be function - I can use view, procedure, function or anything else as long as I can save my sql statement and just pass ids as parameter.
I'm also fine with passing SQL that produces the ids I need so something like

```
select my_function("select id from projects where name like '%qwerty%'")
```

is also fine.

Of course in real word this statement is much harder than this example and writing it each time is not only hard but can also be error-prone

Comment: 'writing it each time is not only hard but can also be error-prone' - and passing parameters is not?

Comment: Well when I pass parameter I can only make mistake in the ids I pass to a method. If however I write full sql statement (with multiple where, group by and joins) then I guess there is a lot more place for mistake :)